# Using _.some | _.any properly for lo-dash or underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, underscore.js, momentjs

I'm trying to see if any of the days are '01-01' ( the beginning of the year )

```
_.some(a.days, function(day){ console.log(day.date.format('DD-MM')) }, "01-01")
```

Produces this array of dates in my console :

```
01-01
02-01
03-01
04-01
05-01
06-01
07-01
```

So then I run without the `console.log` like so .. :

```
_.some(a.days, function(day){ day.date.format('DD-MM') }, "01-01")
```

And it returns :

```
false
```

Strange, eh? What do you think I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Btw if anyone came here inadvertently looking for the difference between 'some' and 'any', they are aliases and do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You've misunderstood what the last argument to `_.some` is. The [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#some) shows that it is the `context`, or scope, under which the iterator function runs, but it seems like you're trying to use it as a value for equality testing.

You'll need to explicitly execute the equality test yourself.

```
_.some(a.days, function(day) {
    return day.date.format('DD-MM') === "01-01";
});
```

Answer (score 18):

You appear to be misunderstanding how to use `_.some()`. Consult the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#some) and you'll see that your function needs to return `true` or `false`, and the last argument will be used as `this` in tat function.

You need to do this instead:

```
_.some(a.days,function(day){ return day.date.format("DD-MM") == "01-01";});
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. This is absolutely correct. I could only choose one though so I went with the underdog :(